How to query in firebase with OR operator, whose query parameters are different?
I am trying to implement OR operator in firebase query. I searched but couldn't find similar usage that I intend, for example this answer doesn't apply to mine. I want all occurences to get returned in my query. I am trying to do something like this:
query(collection(db, "users"),
  where("town", "==", user.town) OR
  where("city", "==", user.city) OR
  where("country", "==", user.country), (snapshot) => { ... }

As can be seen, I am trying to return all instances, and the query parameters are not the same. Is there a way to do this in firebase?

See this answer and the documentation for logical or queries.

@DougStevenson ok thank you!
